# Return a one to many set of rows in mysql without duplication

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a database of `users` and `user items` of which each user can have multiple items linked to their account.

The problem im having with my current `SELECT` query is I want to return each user once but with all the rows tied to that user sort of like this:

```
User 1 ¬
      item id 1
      item id 2
      item id 3
User 2 ¬
      item id 1
      item id 3
      etc
```

This would be my ideal fetch results so i can process the data correctly by simple looping... so i tried a `left join` but this did not work.

I am wondering how do I fetch the results like the above? This is my current query:

```
SELECT U.user_id, I.item_name  
FROM users U
LEFT JOIN user_items UI ON U.user_id = UI.user_id
INNER JOIN items I ON I.item_id = UI.item_id
```

Currently if a user has two or more items, I get duplicated data for User ID which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you are trying to traverse a master/detail relationship.

Whenever you use JOINs, the engine will output every matching set of rows. In this case, if a user has more than 1 item, it will appear along with every one of them. That is not something you can avoid, as you cannot have a result set with a varying amount of columns or something like "do not output this column if the previous one has the same value". I wouldn't try to solve it adjusting the query. The LEFT JOIN will only help you if you want to have also every user that doesn't have any items.

In order to get the output you want, you need to work with the result set. For instance, you could order the results by user_id, then traverse the set and printing the user_id only when it changes. Another option would be to use 2 queries: one to get every user (you can narrow it to every one that has at least one item, if you want), and another to get the items for each user, traversing the results from the first query.

Both solutions require you to process the results, by means of a stored procedure, or a programming language.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm im surprised MYSQL has such a limitation =/